# How to use string values for layout field of content elements?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tsconfig

When using CASE, (such as for layout or frame options) I would like to use words instead of numbers so that it's easier to see what each item is for.

According to the documentation this should work as long as I avoid the words that have special meaning like “if”, “setCurrent”, “key”, and “stdWrap” and “default”

However when I use any of these values in TS Config:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.addItems {
    banner-home = Banner Home
    banner_home = Banner Home
    bannerHome = Banner Home
    bannerhome = Banner Home
}
```

the content element will not save it and the layout dropdown reverts to Default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the layout field of tt_content is

```
layout int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
```

you need to change the field type first to be able to store non numeric values.

Changes to the database structure can be applied through `ext_tables.sql` files within your own extension. Make sure your extension is loaded after the existing extension, which is defining `int(11)` for this field. Add a `depends` entry inside `ext_emconf.php` to do so.

See:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-tables-sql
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-emconf-php

Comment: @user500665 the answer was extended to include these information